# Whether there is a this type function module that shows a file's functions in PyCharm?

Tags: xcode, pycharm

Is there a function module like Xcode to shows a file's functions in Pycharm?

In Xcode there is a place to shows the file's functions:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I did not find a place for PyCharm to shows the functions.

Whether there is a this type function module in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

Off course there has, in the PyCharm left sidebar, there is a Structure button you can click.

[image]

The `f` stands for function, and maybe the file has variable which should be `v` in there.